# Regex to make the user to enter the specific set of values

Tags: regex

Iam looking for Regex which can accept values between 1 and 250 .The Following values should not be accepted ("'!@#$)$()(_+) and -1-2-3-4 and so on

```
/^[1-9][0-9][0-9]?$/
```

Comment: What language is this in? Range checking (in every language I can think of off the top of my head) is typically easier if you just cast/parse to an `int` and do a numerical comparison. Regex is not very good at it.

Comment: @eldarethis: This is Javascript form Validation where we are using different Form Plugin where it accepts Regex

Comment: be aware that client-side validation should never replace, only supplement, server-side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^250|(?:2[0-4]|1[0-9])[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?$/
```

Comment: @lgancio:When i enter Value "1" it is giving me error .It should accept "1" also

Comment: Recheck your typing. `1` is covered by the third alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using numeric comparison operators.

But if you want a regex for it here you go:

```
^(?:250|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Note that this allows leading zeros, if you don't want them you can see [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263356/regex-to-make-the-user-to-enter-the-specific-set-of-values/4263370#4263370)'s answer.